# Figure <figcaption> doesn't work

Tags: html

I want to use the `HTML5` `figcaption` tag to align some text under the picture:

```css
.imagesize {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <img src = "http://i67.tinypic.com/vf8tcn.jpg" class="imagesize img-responsive center-block"/>
<figcaption>Linus Torvalds, the creator of Linux and Git</figcaption>
</figure>
```

This is the **codepen** [link](http://codepen.io/bogdan1/pen/egzaBq) to my project where you can see the full source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it centered, here is one way, adding this rule

```
figcaption {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.imagesize {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
figcaption {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <img src = "http://i67.tinypic.com/vf8tcn.jpg" class="imagesize img-responsive center-block"/>
<figcaption>Linus Torvalds, the creator of Linux and Git</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

Here is another

```
figcaption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.imagesize {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
figcaption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <img src = "http://i67.tinypic.com/vf8tcn.jpg" class="imagesize img-responsive center-block"/>
<figcaption>Linus Torvalds, the creator of Linux and Git</figcaption>
</figure>
```